# Spyder not starting AttributeError: module 'asycio' has no attribute 'WindowsSelectorLoopPolicy'

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I activate my environment and launch from the conda command line

```
> activate myenv
> spyder
```

but I get this error:
[image]

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove my environment `conda remove -n envname --all` and then `conda create -n envname` followed by `activate envname` then `conda install -c anaconda spyder`.

Seems that there is an issue with my old environments and a recent update I performed.
Now I have to just install the rest of the packages into this environment as clone from previous one wont even allow spyder4 to be installed.